# Jsoup code that works for Eclipse but not Android Studio (httpurlconnectionimpl)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am working on a small app for myself and I just don't understand why my code is working in Eclipse but not on my phone using Android Studio.

```
public static ArrayList<Link> getLinksToChoose(String searchUrl) {

  ArrayList<Link> linkList = new ArrayList<Link>();  
    try {
        System.out.println(searchUrl);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchUrl).timeout(3000).userAgent("Chrome").get();  
        Elements links = doc.select("tr");  
        links.remove(0);    
        Elements newLinks = new Elements();

        for(Element link : links) {
            Link newLink = new Link(getURL(link),getName(link),getLang(link));
            linkList.add(newLink);
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

The problem is I can't even get the Document. I always get an httpurlconnectionimpl in the line where I try to get the html doc. I have read a bit about Jsoup in Android. Some people suggest using AsyncTask but  it doesn't seem like that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading of the content must happen outside the main thread, e.g. in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you. If anyone is going to read this, I also had to add internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and now it's working the way it should.